# Alias Column In Resultset

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a query in backend spring project, where I create a field alias named agent_id but I don´t have that column in Model. What is the best approach for showing this as a field in table view in front end???.
Here´s the query:

```
 Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT" +
                "  ips.*, " +
                "  s.mls_id AS imported," +
                "  p.INTEGRATOR_SALES_ASSOCIATED_ID AS agent_id " +
                "FROM test1.ilist_property_summary ips " +
                "  LEFT JOIN test1.statistics s ON s.mls_id = ips.INTEGRATOR_PROPERTY_ID " +
                "  LEFT JOIN test1.person p ON p.INTEGRATOR_SALES_ASSOCIATED_ID = ips.INTEGRATOR_SALES_ASSOCIATED_ID " +
                "WHERE ips.AGENCY_ID = :agencyId AND (s.statistics_type = 1 OR s.statistics_type IS NULL) AND ips.ORIG_LISTING_DATE BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate");

        query.setParameter("agencyId", agencyId)
                .setParameter("startDate", DateUtil.asDate(startDate), TemporalType.DATE)
                .setParameter("endDate", DateUtil.asDate(endDate), TemporalType.DATE);


        return (List<PropertyVO>) query.getResultList().stream().map(o -> processProperty((Object[]) o)).collect(Collectors.<PropertyVO>toList());
```

I already have a field that shows agent_id, but not fetched with same field of table Person. I need to retrieve that field agent id alias fetched from left join.

Comment: First you shouldn't use ips.* because the filed order could change. Then what do you exactly want to achieve? Just displaying the result set as a table in the frontend?

Comment: I want to display those fields in a table in frontend, I already have working as an API and it returns this: `     [{"id":1936041,"origListingDate":"2017-01-16 00:00:00.0","address":"","agent":"420041019","price":53000.0,"currency":"USD","contractType":1,"transactionType":2,"imported":false,"mlsid":"420041019-292"},`     . But I want to show that alias column that I don´t have defined as a column in the model.

Comment: if you want to use the model you have to add the field to the model. There is no other way.

Comment: Is there a way to show this field, without using the model??

Comment: I read that creating a Transient field in model is a way.... Is it advisable?

Comment: When you talk about the model you mean PropertyVO?

Comment: Yes, that´s the model.

Comment: as you are converting the result of the query to PropertyVO then you must add the agent_id to PropertyVO

Comment: I already have it, but it shows all agent id values, and I want to show those values as result of fetching left join with table Person. It would return agent id for fetched records and null for those that doesn´t have a corresponding match in table person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed another approach:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT" +
                "  ips.id, ips.agency_id, ips.integrator_property_id, ips.orig_listing_date, ips.contract_type," +
                "  ips.transaction_type, ips.current_listing_price, ips.current_listing_currency, ips.apartment_number, ips.commercial_residential," +
                "  ips.commission_percent, ips.commission_value, ips.property_type, ips.street_name, ips.street_number," +
                "  s.mls_id AS imported," +
                "  p.INTEGRATOR_SALES_ASSOCIATED_ID  AS INTEGRATOR_SALES_ASSOCIATED_ID" +
                "  FROM test1.ilist_property_summary ips " +
                "  LEFT JOIN test1.statistics s ON s.mls_id = ips.INTEGRATOR_PROPERTY_ID " +
                "  LEFT JOIN test1.person p ON p.INTEGRATOR_SALES_ASSOCIATED_ID = ips.INTEGRATOR_SALES_ASSOCIATED_ID " +
                "WHERE ips.AGENCY_ID = :agencyId AND (s.statistics_type = 1 OR s.statistics_type IS NULL) AND ips.ORIG_LISTING_DATE BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate ");
```

Here field

```
INTEGRATOR_SALES_ASSOCIATED_ID
```

is taken from table p, and not from ips. I just selected specific fields so this one could be taken from the other table.